# how to Make FirstPersonController object Static/not moving when Placed over Moving Terrain in unity 3D

Tags: static, unity-game-engine, terrain

I created a terrain and applied constantForce on this terrain, then I Placed FirstPersonController Object Over this Terrain.

FirstPersonController Object moves or change its position due it is over moving terrain, I wanna  make FirstPersonController not moving/static.

so how can I make FirstPersonController or GameObect  static over moving terrain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [Character Motor] component, uncheck [Movin Platform -> enable], maybe this will help you. I am using Unity 4.3.4.

Comment: how can I make Static/not moving Cube over Moving terrain and thanks for your answer it really helps me

Comment: If you want cube moving with terrain, maybe you can set the cube's parent = terrain.